# Why do “Meer” and “See” have swapped meanings from their Dutch counterparts?

Tags: etymology

In German *das Meer* means *the sea – zee* in Dutch. *Die See* means *the lake – meer* in Dutch.

We see that these words are used reciprocal to the Dutch words for sea and lake. Why is that? *Meer* in Dutch means *more* too. Does the German *meer* has a comparable meaning, so maybe this is the reason for the different usage, because there is more (*meer*) water in the sea?

Comment: In Stack Exchange we expect people to do a little research before asking. Which dictionary did you try?

Comment: did someone already mention the play-with-words: Wenn ich einen See seh', brauch' ich kein Meer mehr.

Comment: In Afrikaans we also have that hominem, meer being a lake and the word for more. You could say meer water in die meer, if you really wanted to.

Comment: @Prishon: In German "*die* See" does **not** mean lake, it means sea; just like "Meer". "*Der* See" means lake. See answer from Hubert Schölnast.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In German we have the homophone but differently spellt word 'mehr' in the meaning of more.

As to the difference of the Dutch and German for *zee* and *meer* vs *der See* and *das Meer*: it is true, but not so clear. There is also *die See* with the same meaning as *das Meer* (zee). This reflects also in the German names for North Sea (Nordsee) and Baltic sea (Ostsee), but also the names of many lakes in northern Germany like 'Steinhuder Meer', 'Zwischenahner Meer' etc.

Generally the meaning of the words in the northern German dialects used to be identical to the Dutch usage while in southern German dialects saw usages as in standard German nowadays.

Comment: Isnt the Mediterenean called Mittelmeer in whole Germany?

Comment: Yes, it is. Influenced surely more by the southern German speakers than the northern ones.

Comment: @planetmaker That's a weird statement. For most of the time period when the German language developed, Rome was considered the center of the world. Why do you believe there should be a difference between North and South Germany in how this sea should be called?

Comment: @Roland Presumably South Germans had more often occasions to speak about the Mediterranean, due to their greater physical proximity. Similarly to how the Nordsee is influenced by Northern Germanic usage, despite being to the North of both.

Comment: @DenisNardin I doubt that. During the middle ages the main reason to talk about this sea was in conjunction with Italy and the Pope or for mercants. There wasn't much difference between North and South in this regard as nobels and clerics from all of Germany were catholics and trade lines went from the Baltic and North Sea coast all the way through Germany and Austria to Italy.

Comment: @Roland Nitpicking, but actually at least the merchants from Venice that did commerce in the Netherlands went all the way through Gibraltar and around Spain and France (it was still simpler than crossing the Alps with merchandise!)...

Comment: Kinda weird that those living far away from saltwater developed different words for seas and lakes while those who actually do live close to the sea developed a more muddied distinction between the two words.

Comment: The literal translation of Ostsee being East Sea? Like the East of Pretoria being referred to as the  oste by some?

Comment: Yes, like that. Makes one wonders why North Sea is not called Westsee.

Comment: @Roland The (High)German language split off from other Germanic languages around the 7th century, in a region mostly south of the Roman Limes, far from the sea.  Though Charlemagne subjugated the Saxons (since renamed Low-Saxons) and Angles, outside of aristocracy (High)German only started encroaching on the northern Low-German about 150 years ago.  Even when North-Germans speak German, they retain some influence of Low-German such as "hohe See" (high seas), "seetüchtig" (seaworthy), "seekrank" (sea sick) or "Seemann/Seefahrer/zur See fahrn" (sailor), rather than the Latin-German "Meer-"…

Comment: Also, the official naval rank is *Kapitän zur See*, not *zum Meer*. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_(naval)#Germany Analogical to Dutch *Kapitein-ter-zee*

Comment: Es ist auch die Seefahrt. So any nautical term is very likely to use 'See'.

Comment: thx @sermonionx

Answer (score 39):

The German feminine noun *"**die** See"* doesn't mean English *"lake"* or Dutch *"meer".* Here are the correct translations:

| German | English | Dutch |
| --- | --- | --- |
| das Meer | the sea | de zee |
| **die** See | the sea | de zee |
| **der** See | the lake | het meer |
| mehr | more | meer |

---

### *Ger* der See, *Ger* die See, *Eng* the sea, *Dut* de zee

Etymologists are sure that both German nouns *"der See"* and *"die See",* the English noun *"the sea"* and the Dutch noun *"de zee"* have the same etymological root, but it is unclear what exactly this common root is. Some say it comes from an old word for *"water bucket"* or *"tub".* Others think it might be related to a verb that means *"to pour"* or *"to drip",* and there is also another old word that sounds similar which means *"water collecting in rivulets".*

All in all it seams to me as if the ancestor of See/sea/zee was used for smaller amounts of water at the beginning (like ponds and lakes) and then got used more and more for bigger water bodies.

---

### *Ger* das Meer, *Dut* het meer

This word was in latin language *"mare"* and was a synonym for *"oceanus"* and both words meant *the sea, the ocean.* But similar words in related old languages meant *"bog, marsh"* or *"morass"* (German: *Moor, Sumpf, Morast, Marschland*) but also *pond* (Ger: *Teich*) or *puddle* (Ger: *Pfütze, Pfuhl*)

---

### *Ger* mehr, *Eng* more, *Dut* meer

Also these words are cognates and the common ancestor meant *"big", "famous", "wellknown".* Another offsprings of this etymological root are German *"die Mär"* and *"das Märchen"* (Engl: *story, fairy tale*)

---

### Conclusion #1

Both word groups around the words *["das Meer", "het meer"]* and *["der/die See", "the sea", "de zee"]* have been used in many Germanic languages to name bodies of standing water of any size (puddles, ponds, lakes, seas and oceans).

### Conclusion #2

- There is no relationship between German *"das Meer"* and German *"mehr".*
- There also is no etymological relationship between Dutch *"het meer"* (the lake) and Dutch *"meer"* (more).
- Also German *"das Moor"* (gob, marsh) is not related to English *"more"* although they are pronounced almost identically in Received Pronunciation.
- (Also English *"the sea"* and *"to see"* aren't cognates)

Comment: "Ger mehr, Eng moor, Dut meer
" - was this meant to be "more"?

Comment: What about English word moor as in "Hound of the Baskervilles", surely that is related to German "das Moor" (gob, marsh)?

Comment: @JosephDoggie: I also believe, that German *»das Moor«* and English *»the moor«* are etymological cognates, although they don't mean exactly the same kinds of landscape. A German *Moor* is always wet. Sometimes it's even so muddy, that it's impossible to stand or walk on it. In English it is *bog, marsh, swamp,* but of coarse also *moor.* English *moor* can be wet sometimes, but it also can be a dry habitat with low vegetation like savannas and grasslands. In German such a region where you can walk without getting wet feed isn't called *Moor* but *Heide*.

Comment: Reading about the origin of *Meer* being Latin *mare* makes me wonder whether it is *Mittelmeer* simply because of the prevalence of the Latin name?

Comment: @Jan: The Latin name of the Mediterranean sea is *"mare nostrum"*. If the German Name would derive directly from the latin name it wouldn't be *"Mittelmeer"* ("middle sea") but *"Unsermeer"* because *"nostrum"* is *"unser"* in German (*"our"* in English). Btw: *"Nordee"* was *"mare germanicum"* in Latin which is *"Germanic sea"* in English and *"Germanenmeer"* in German.

Comment: At least locally Meer in German was used to mean marsh/bog relatively recently. There's a street in the city of Essen called [Schwarze Meer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Stra%C3%9Fen_in_Essen-Stadtkern) which (indirectly) refers to a local marsh and not the black sea.

Comment: Could also mention the English word [mere](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mere) (see sense "noun (1)") which, like Dutch _meer_ means "lake".

Comment: you also have mermaid (zeemeermin) which has zee and meer in it.
And in French the North Sea is la mer du Nord.

Comment: Also as @Maeher says, in Geman there are lakes with "Meer" in their name as well (though you would never use "Meer" as a generic term for a lake).

Comment: Latin was spoken for over a thousand years and the Mediterranean had several names over that time. By the fall of the Western Roman Empire, the name *Mare Mediterraneum* is attested (and most if not all Romance languages use a direct derivation of that name, as does English). This literally mean “earth-middle sea” (where “earth” could mean either land or world). *Mittelmeer* is likely a shortened translation of that. @Jan It's more complicated than “*Meer* from Latin, *See* otherwise” though, since there's e.g. *Japanisches Meer* but *Javasee*.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks for the insight! Yes; if anything, I would have assumed that rule to hold true no further than what might have had a German name by the end of the Old German period or maybe the late Middle German. Meaning everything named after that would have followed completely different rules, if any.

Comment: currently this answer appears to suggest that German Meer, Dutch meer, & English mere *derive* from Latin mare. This is incorrect. They are cognate with it, with all forms deriving from Proto-Indo-European *móri. Interestingly, whilst the Germanic vowels are entirely as expected, the expected Latin form would be *more so the Latin actually seems more likely to have been borrowed (from the other, or another Indo-European source), if either is borrowed

Answer (score 1):

Agree with previous posters, but I see the word "Meer" being used as a word play between "more" and "sea/ocean".

https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=1183233818481715

Also used in a series from ARD [*Verrückt nach Meer*](https://www.daserste.de/information/reportage-dokumentation/verrueckt-nach-meer/index.html) which means something like "crazy about / longing for the see", but has the word play that you want *more*. (the series is a docusoap about cruise liners and their guests)

There are several other similar word plays in German.

Comment: This word play is based on the fact that *Meer* and *mehr* are homophones. But being homonyms is no evidence pro or contra real etymological relationship. A word play is just a joke that doesn't really give one word the meaning of the other.

Comment: There is also a song about Lake Constance titled *Wenn ich den See seh', brauche ich kein Meer mehr.*

Comment: There is also a word play _Meer und mehr_. and like many similar puns, is detrimental, since it propagates [false etymology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folk_etymology).

Answer (score 0):

Für einen Kommentar etwas zu lang, jedoch noch ohne Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit.:

Angenomen, in Holland herschen in Küstennähe salzhaltige Seen vor, wäre das ein entscheidender Unterschied. Wo Meerwasser ist, da ist Meer, leuchtet doch ein.

Da *See* wiederum von unsicherer Herkunft ist, lässt sich wenig über diesen Wandel sagen, außer dass Englisch zumindest mit der Oranje übereinstimmt, doch auch zu Deutsch heißt es noch *Hochsee*. Der Bodensee könnte auch als kleines Meer gelten, wenngleich die Salzhaltigkeit dabei dann keine Rolle spielen dürfte, was geradezu paradox wäre angesichts *sel* "Salz" als plausiblen Ansatz unter kompensatorischer Längung (als ob *Sel-Meer)